# Stop background apps permanently Android

Tags: android, performance, background-process

I am curious how apps like Task Managers & a specific app named Purify are able to permanently stop(force stop) background apps without requiring root permissions.

I searched & found a few ways but they were not efficient enough to stop all apps.

First method I found was to use KILLBACKGROUNDPROCESSES function but it was not able to kill all the background apps.

Secondly, I read about the SU FORCE STOP method but it requires root.

How are the apps able to do it without root?

Comment: this can only be done by android. no other app can really terminate a process.

Answer (score 0):

Some Android applications can close other processes that are currently running in the background, not all process can be terminated. Some process even if terminated are restarted immediately. (You can try to close some from the 'application manager' and see for yourself).

You could try the following code that i compiled, it allows you to specify which processes that you may not want to kill.

```
// List of packages not to kill
    List<String> reservedPackages = new ArrayList<String>();
    reservedPackages.add("system");
    reservedPackages.add("com.android.launcher2");
    reservedPackages.add("com.android.inputmethod.latin");
    reservedPackages.add("com.android.phone");
    reservedPackages.add("com.android.wallpaper");
    reservedPackages.add("com.google.process.gapps");
    reservedPackages.add("android.process.acore");
    reservedPackages.add("android.process.media");

    //kill all except that in the list above
    int processKillCounter = 0;
    ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) this.getBaseContext().getSystemService(Activity.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> listeProcessus = am.getRunningAppProcesses();
    for(ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo processus : listeProcessus) {
        String packageName = processus.processName.split(":")[0];
        if (!this.getBaseContext().getPackageName().equals(packageName) && !reservedPackages.contains(packageName)) {
            am.restartPackage(packageName);
            processKillCounter++;
        }
    }

         mi = new ActivityManager.MemoryInfo();
         activityManager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        activityManager.getMemoryInfo(mi);
        long afterBoostMemory = mi.availMem / 1048576L;

        long boostedMemory =  afterBoostMemory - availableMegs;

        //Percentage can be calculated for API 16+
        long percentAvail = mi.availMem / mi.totalMem;
        Toast.makeText(this,"Phone Boosted, "+boostedMemory + " MB freed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```